# How I can get the column names from a query using doctrine 2?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I need to get the names of the columns in a sql query executed by doctrine 2.

This worked for me in doctrine 1.2

```
public function executeQuery($query, $conn) {

    /*.......*/

    $result = $conn->execute($query);

    $array_result = array();
    $long = $result->columnCount();

    while ($long > $iterator) {
        $meta = $result->getColumnMeta($iterator);
        $array_result[$iterator]['name'] = $meta['name'];
        $array_result[$iterator]['type'] = $meta['native_type'];
        $iterator++;
    }
    return $array_result;
}
```

I am now working with symfony 2 and doctrine 2. I need to get the name and data type fields in the `SELECT` clause. Example:

```
SELECT name, lastname FROM profile
```

I need to get the name and lastname fields from php using doctrine.

Comment: I've tried everything, and I've looked everywhere and still not solve my problem, I tried running the query with doctrine, but can not find any method that gives me the fields that I have in the select query

Comment: You comment "I've tried everything". Post your two most promising approaches and also let us know what the exact error return is. Otherwise this is like walking to the doctor, telling him you're ill, but you don't give any other information and don't let him do any examination.